# How do I get multiple records from an indexedDB index using NgxIndexedDB?

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I have created an IndexedDB database using [NgxIndexedDB](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-indexed-db) and created an index which is not unique. When I read the records using `getByIndex()` it's returning only one record although I know there are more records matching. What is the mechanism to get all matching records ?

```
this.db = new NgxIndexedDB(‘mydb’, 1);
this.db.openDatabase(1, evt => {
  let objectStore = evt.currentTarget.result.createObjectStore(‘amp’, 
    {keyPath: '_id', autoIncrement: false });
  console.log("Open DB is called...")
  objectStore.createIndex(‘empname’, ‘empname’, { unique: false });
});

this.db.getByIndex(‘amp,’empname’,’Dave’).then(names => {
  console.log(names);
  resolve(names);  
},
error => {
  console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: Please provide the definition of getByIndex or a more detailed description of NgxIndexedDB. It is needed to help answer your question.

Comment: I have used this based on the information given here.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-indexed-db
( npm install ngx-indexed-db) 

    getByIndex(storeName: string, indexName: string, key: any): Promise<any>;

This is the usage example given there

db.getByIndex('people', 'name', 'Dave').then(
    person => {
        console.log(person);
    },
    error => {
        console.log(error);
    }
);

Comment: I have edited the question to add the reference doc

Comment: The docs say getByIndex returns a single item. Have you tried using getAll? https://github.com/assuncaocharles/ngx-indexed-db/blob/master/projects/ngx-indexed-db/src/lib/ngx-indexed-db.ts#L52

Comment: I have tried getALL(without Any Argument). it is retrieving the entire set of records in collection. But I need only for that specific matching condition. 


But they had mentioned one more parameter to getAll, i.e. index details.I am not sure whether that will work?

 getAll(storeName: string, keyRange?: IDBKeyRange, indexDetails?: IndexDetails): Promise<any>;

But I have tried but not successful to make that call and is retuning error

Comment: Josh, I was able to make it working it by getAll() as suggested. Thanks for input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some trial and error, I was able to do it using getAll functions as per the clue from Josh. Thanks Josh. Here is the way.

```
  this.db.openDatabase(1, evt => {
      let objectStore = evt.currentTarget.result.createObjectStore(‘empCollection’, { keyPath: '_id', autoIncrement: false });
      console.log("Open DB is called...")
      objectStore.createIndex(‘empname’, ‘empname’, { unique: false });
    });


    let index_detail:IndexDetails = {
      indexName: 'empname',
      order: 'asc'
    }


 this.db.getAll(‘empCollection’,IDBKeyRange.only(“Dave”),index_details).then(
          names => {
            console.log(names);
          },
          error => {
            console.log(error);
          }
        );
```

Comment: how did you return a value in
this.db.getAll(‘empCollection’,IDBKeyRange.only(“Dave”),index_details).then(
          names => {
            console.log(names);
          },
          error => {
            console.log(error);
          }
        );

Comment: Search conditions you can mention in indexdetails

Comment: sorry please can you explain better?

Comment: I am not sure whether I understood your question well. in normal case  this.db.getAll(‘empCollection’).then(
  outpout => {
   console.log(output);  ==>>OUTPUT===>>
  },
  error => {
   console.log(error);
 }
);  this query returns list of all records in that collection records  in "output" variable , which I have printed out in console for testing.   The specific post I have  put is to show, instead of all records , I want to filter the records with some matching conditions ( here all records which contains the name "Dave".. if you need more info, pl explain elaborate your question

Comment: here output will be a json array list "names"